# Включить клик js в ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, href

На одной странице сайта есть ссылка-спойлер, то есть при клике на нее под ней появляется блок: с помощью js кода идет подмена стиля с `display:none` на `display:block`.

Нужно сформировать такую ссылку, чтобы она вела на эту страницу сайта с открытым спойлером, как это можно сделать?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_ico btn_order" ><span>Открыть спойлер</span></a>
```

P.S. JS код не буду приводить так как он там большой и запутан. Думаю, вопрос и так понятен.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять к ссылке какое-нибудь значение и на нужной странице обрабатывать.

В JS не шарю, напишу на JQ. Как бы глупо не звучало..

```js
// Код не связанный с ответом
$('a').on('click',function(){
  console.info('Типо браузер перешёл по ссылке '+$(this).attr('href'));
  // Далее имитации $(window).onload();
  windowOnload();
  return false;
});

function windowOnload() {
  let thisUrl = location.href; // Т.к. код в сниппете, то этот метод не сработает, по этому имитируем и его.
  thisUrl = 'ссылка?spoiler=test'.split('?')[1].split('='); //Сразу разобъём его по разделителю и на действия. (слишком некорректное действие, но для наглядности пойдёт)
  let act = thisUrl[0], // действие, в нашем случае "spoiler"
      actID = thisUrl[1]; // ну и ID спойлера.
  if(act == 'spoiler') { // Ну думаю понятно
    let elem = $('#'+actID+'.spoiler'); // определим, как должен "выглядеть" блок спойлера с его IDом.
    if(elem.length) { // Если такой блок есть, то..
      // Выполняйте Ваш скрипт на открытие, я просто заменю "Закрыт" на "Открыт".
      $(elem).text('Открыт');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="ссылка?spoiler=test">Ссылка</a>

<div id="test" class="spoiler">Закрыт</div>

<!--
ссылка - адрес документа. Ваш кэп.
? - разделитель
spoiler - "идентификатор" действия
test - в нашем случае, идентификатор спойлера

Ссылка работать не будет, по этому сделаю имитацию.
Дальше будет блок
-->
```

Надеюсь смысл понятен..

Comment: **P.s** Надоели люди, которые минусят без причины. **Минус без причины, признак дурачины** (без обид)

Comment: Как можно не шарить в `js` и при этом писать код на `jq`? )))

Comment: @Air, странно звучит, да? Просто сразу начал учить JQ :D

Comment: Не то. Если ставлю ссылку, при нажатии на "Открыть спойлер" обновляется страница с добавлением с url текста моей ссылки и спойлер опять остается закрытым.

Comment: @VitaliyAntal, так.. Если я правильно понял, ссылка и спойлер находятся на одной странице?

Comment: да, наверное проблема в том, что у меня к ссылке добавляется слеш в начало, то есть получается "урл/?ccылка", а должно быть "урл?ссылка"

Comment: @VitaliyAntal, добавьте код, так будет проще.

Comment: какой именно код?